# Capitalization combinations in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the most efficient way to write a function that generates all combinations of lower case and upper case letters in a word?

ie

```
λ: cap "mat"
["MAT","MAt","MaT","Mat","mAT","mAt","maT","mat"]
```

edit:
@user2407038 has provided

```
cap w =  mapM (\x -> [toLower x, toUpper x]) w
```

which works.

in trying to understand why this works, I find that

```
sequenceA ["mM", "aA", "tT"]
```

gives the correct answer. Maybe someone could help explain why that works

Comment: Is this homework? Wbat have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the list monad.

Comment: `mapM (\x -> [toLower x,toUpper x])`

Comment: @user2407038 You should make that into an answer

Comment: @user2407038 any chance you could explain how that works? thank you

Comment: @chi Code-only answers are bad style and I don't have much to add to my comment (I've been looking for a question about why `mapM` for lists works the way it does but I can't find it).

Comment: I'd use `Applicative` and `Traversable` rather than `Monad`. So `traverse (([toUpper,toLower] <*>) . pure)`. Because we're *traversing* the word, but using the *choice* structure for the upper/lower-case distinction.

Comment: @pigworker In this case it won't make a difference, since `mapM = traverse` for `[]`

Comment: Yeah, using worse syntax when the data type being operated on is known to be a monad anyway is kind of pointless IMO.

Comment: Here's a point-free formulation of the same thing, just because: `(traverse.sequenceA) [toLower,toUpper]`. Alternatively, using the Functor instance of `[]` instead of the Applicative instance of `->` and the [`??` operator in lens](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.18/lens-4.15.4/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-): `traverse ([toLower,toUpper]??)`

Comment: @4castle In *this* case, but it's the wrong lesson. `traverse` is the more powerful tool to understand. `mapM` is a historic accident.

Answer (score 2):

The applicative `<*>` operator applies each in a list of functions to each of a list of operands.  With it you can write cap like this:

```
cap :: String -> [String]
cap "" = pure ""
cap (c:cs) = (:) <$> [toLower c, toUpper c] <*> cap cs
```

The `<$>` is infix `fmap`, and applies the cons function to each element of `[toLower c, toUpper c]`.  This creates a two-element list of functions, one of which cons-es the lower-case `c` onto a string, and the other cons-es the upper-case `c` onto a string.  This is then sequentially applied to `cap cs`.

Edit: Oh good, `mapM (\x -> [toLower x,toUpper ])` is in one of the comments and definitely better than this.

Edit 2: Do what u/pigworker said:

```
cap :: String -> [String]
cap = traverse (\x -> [toLower x, toUpper x])
```

Comment: Good to go with Applicative. But replace your `[""]` with `pure ""` and you'll see you just wrote a special case of `traverse` (i.e. `mapM`, but `mapM` should not exist any more, because it asks for `Monad` when it needs only `Applicative`).

Comment: Amaze your friends, Confuse your enemies! `traverse (sequence [toLower, toUpper])`, just $19.99!